# Prove that the successor Y of node X, when X doesn't have right child, is the lowest ancestor of X

Tags: data-structures, binary-search-tree, proof

I study CS in the university and I've got a question I'm having problem proving.

> Prove that the successor `Y` of node `X` on a BST, when `X` doesn't have right child, is the lowest ancestor of `X`, that is left child is also an ancestor of `X`.

I need to consider all cases, including leaf, except the rightmost because he has no successor.

Can you guys give me some hints from where to start?

Comment: Start by drawing pictures of trees and then work your way through inorder traversals. You should find the pattern quickly enough.

Comment: I understand it's true but I can't figure out how to prove it.

Answer (score 4):

An inorder traversal of a BST node visits the left subtree, the node itself, and then the right subtree.

So, if `X` (which doesn't have a right child) is the left child of its parent, then we know that its successor is the parent. This follows from the definition of inorder traversal.

If `X` is the right child of its parent, then the parent precedes it in the traversal (although it's not the *immediate* predecessor unless `X` has no left subtree). This, too, follows from the definition of inorder traversal. The successor of `X`, since it doesn't have a right subtree, must be above it in the tree. The successor can't be the parent, so it must be what the parent's successor would be if `X` didn't exist.

Comment: Ok, but in my opinion this does not answer the question, and, if it does, it makes you think recursively...

Comment: Lots of proofs are done recursively. Explain how this does not answer the question.

Comment: First of all, you need to have a clear idea of an in-order traversal, which is not always the case. Moreover the in-order traversal does not tell much _intuitively_ about the successor, IMHO. So, yes, as I also said in the previous comment, it may answer the question, but it's a recursive explanation. Indeed after reading a few more times I reached the conclusion that this actually answers the question (recursive understanding). Violating the principle of non contradiction allows me to excuse myself eventually :D

Comment: By the way I had already upvoted your answer even before commenting ;)